# How can I use `scp` to deploy a website's `.htaccess` file?

Tags: .htaccess, deployment, scp, shared-hosting

I am currently using the following command to upload my site content:

```
scp -r web/* user@site.com:site.com/
```

This works great except that the .htaccess file is not sent. Presumably, this is because it's hidden.

I have tried adding a second line to send the file explicitely:

```
scp -r web/.htaccess user@site.com:site.com/.htaccess
```

This works great except now I have to enter my password twice.

Any thoughts on how to make this deploy with only 1 or 0 entries of my password?

Comment: use rsync rather than scp, that way only newer files will be copied, saving time :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just combine the two commands:

```
scp -r web/* web/.htaccess user@site.com:site.com/
```

If you want 0 entries of your password you can set up [public key authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/) for ssh/scp.

Answer (score 4):

Some background info: the `*` wildcard does not match so-called "dot-files" (i.e. files whose name begins with a dot).

Some shells allow you to set an option, so that it *will* match dot-files, however, doing that is asking for a lot of pain: now `*` will also match `.` (the current directory) and `..` (the parent directory), which is usually not what is intended and can be quite surprising! (`rm -rf *` deleting the parent directory is probably not the best way to start a day ...)

Answer (score 3):

A word of caution - don't attempt to match dotted files (like `.htaccess`) with `.*` - this inconveniently also matches `..`, and would result in copying all the files on the path to the root directory. I did this once (with `rm`, no less!) and I had to rebuild the server because I'd messed with `/var`.

@jwmittag:

I just did a test on Ubuntu and `.*` matches when I use `cp`. Here's an example:

```
root@krash:/# mkdir a
root@krash:/# mkdir b
root@krash:/# mkdir a/c
root@krash:/# touch a/d
root@krash:/# touch a/c/e
root@krash:/# cp -r a/c/.* b
cp: will not create hard link `b/c' to directory `b/.'
root@krash:/# ls b
d  e
```

If `.*` did not match `..`, then `d` shouldn't be in `b`.

Comment: I'm talking about the '*' wildcard all by itself. It won't match files beginning with a dot. '.*' will match all files beginning with a dot, including the special directories '.' and '..'.